# I want to delete duplicate rows from a MySQL table. Please click on the below link to see the table data

Tags: mysql-workbench

I tried to do it with this query, but it's not working...

```
DELETE FROM employee 
    WHERE ( SELECT * FROM
            (SELECT row_number() OVER (partition by id) rn FROM employee) alias
          ) > 1;
```

[Please click on this link to view the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TH9Eo.png)

The above query is not working and giving this error message:

> Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: You should tag **one** specific database product not **three**.. But If you are looking for a query that works between database systems you should only have the `sql` tag

Comment: When we see the title of your question _I want to delete duplicate rows using this query only_ so you don't want another query it must this one which is wrong.

Comment: Also for better answers you can also better post the table structure(s) the `CREATE TABLE` statement(s) ... `Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row` seams to be MySQL related error so you should be able to do `SHOW CREATE TABLE employee`

Comment: Also see [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) for providing example data and expected results

Comment: You cannot delete rows using a syntactically incorrect SQL statement.  That is why you should provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic that you want to implement.

Answer (score 0):

try like below by using subquery

```
   delete from  
      ( 
        select *.row_number() over (partition by id order by id) rn
        from employee  
      ) alias where rn > 1;
```

Comment: what would be the duplicate condition in this question?  I very much doubt the duplicate condition is the id column i assume it's a employee name? it's not clear from the question and query..

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TH9Eo.png

This is the screenshot of my database. So, I just want to delete the duplicate rows and except one of them.

Answer (score 0):

You are matching an integer (1) with set of rows returned from the subquery, which SQL will not allow
You can match an integer (1) with a single value returned from the subquery.

Use below query (using CTE) to remove duplicates.

```
;WITH TempEmp (id,duplicateRecCount)
AS
(
SELECT id,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION by id ORDER BY id) 
AS duplicateRecCount
FROM employee 
)
DELETE FROM TempEmp
WHERE duplicateRecCount > 1
```